# INNER JOIN na mesma tabela

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner

```
SELECT Agendamento.E3TimeStamp AS Data,Agendamento.Lote, Produtos_values.name as NomeProduto, Produtos_ValueData.TemplateID AS mp_produto  
FROM produtos_values  
inner join produtos_valuedata on produtos_values.id = produtos_valuedata.valueid,agendamento
```

Esta `query` funciona certinho, porém preciso fazer outro *`Inner Join`* usando a mesma tabela produtos_values assim:

```
inner join produtos_values on produtos_values.name = agendamento.produto
```

separados eles funcionam mas juntos não, como posso fazer os dois funcionarem ?

Answer (score 3):

da pra voce fazer `inner join` com a mesma tabela utilizando **Alias** diferentes

exemplo:

```
SELECT 
    Agendamento.E3TimeStamp AS Data,Agendamento.Lote, 
    Produtos_values.name as NomeProduto, 
    Produtos_ValueData.TemplateID AS mp_produto

FROM produtos_values pv
inner join produtos_valuedata pvd 
    on pv.id = pvd.valueid.agendamento
inner join produtos_values pvs
    on pv.name = pvs.agendamento.produto;
```

Alias são como apelidos, considere assim.

Answer (score 0):

Desnecessário fazer um `inner join` com a mesma tabela. Utilize `Where`:

```
SELECT Agendamento.E3TimeStamp AS Data,
Agendamento.Lote, Produtos_values.name as NomeProduto,
Produtos_ValueData.TemplateID AS mp_produto
FROM produtos_values
INNER JOIN produtos_valuedata
on produtos_values.id = produtos_valuedata.valueid,agendamento
WHERE produtos_values.name = agendamento.produto;
```